# Find words in String consisting of all distinct characters without using Java Collection Framework

Tags: java

I need your help. I am stuck on one problem, solving it for several hours.

```
 *1. Find word containing only of various characters. Return first word if there are a few of such words.
 2. @param words Input array of words
 3. @return First word that containing only of various characters*


**public String findWordConsistingOfVariousCharacters(String[] words) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You need to implement this method");
}**

@Test
public void testFindWordConsistingOfVariousCharacters() {
    String[] input = new String[] {"aaaaaaawe", "qwer", "128883", "4321"};
    String expectedResult = "qwer";
    StringProcessor stringProcessor = new StringProcessor();
    String result = stringProcessor.findWordConsistingOfVariousCharacters(input);
    assertThat(String.format("Wrong result of method findWordConsistingOfVariousCharacters (input is %s)", Arrays.toString(input)), result, is(expectedResult));
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: "various character" means...?

Comment: So you're supposed to write the `StringProcessor.findWordConsistingOfVariousCharacters` method? That is not at all clear from they way you ask the question. "consisting of various character" also confuses me — it is very vague.

Comment: "I am not allowed to use [HashSet]" sounds like homework. If this is homework you should _**say**_ it's homework, and post the actual question as it's asked.

Comment: I posted actually question being asked

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the data and check whether each string is made up of only distinct characters:

```
    public static boolean repeat(String str) {
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);//The same character will only appear in groups
        
        for(int i = 1;i<chars.length;i++) {
            if(chars[i] == chars[i - 1]) {
                return false;//Same character appeared twice
            }
        }
        return true;//There is no repeating character
    }
```

The method above is used to check whether a string is made up of distinct characters, now loops through the data:

```
for(int i = 0;i<input.length;i++){
    if(repeat(input[i])){
       System.out.println("The answer is " + input[i] + " at index " + i);
       break;//you find it! Now break the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the strings are all ASCII characters, use a boolean[] to mark if you have encountered that character in the word already:

```
 boolean [] encountered = new boolean[256];
 for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
     if (encountered[(int)c]) {
        // not unique
     } else {
        encountered[(int)c] = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: @lierwu Since you aren't the one who asked the question, how do you know? Note that this becomes very complex if you allow full unicode with combining characters etc.  I suspect this question is based on a computer science homework question that isn't intended to delve into that level of complexity.

Comment: You could make the boolean array 65536 long and the solution would work for duplicate 'chars', but it still wouldn't account for the full 32-bit code points of Unicode.

Comment: I don't know, but the statement "string are all ASCII characters" are not correct...

Comment: That's why the solution won't work for all cases...

Comment: @lierwu I stated that as an assumption for my solution. I did not make the claim that it was always true.